# unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder while trying to upgrade to grails 4

Tags: gradle, grails, apache-commons

I am following https://docs.grails.org/4.0.x/guide/upgrading.html and when i try to build my application I am getting the following error.

```
unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder
```

I have tried adding

```
implementation 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
```

and changing the import from

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder
```

to

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder
```

but have had no luck.